# How to set CPU scaling limits System-wide

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, scaling, frequency

I am trying to make my cpu to stay in 2.0GHz (To keep the CPU cool XD) or above with a conservative Governor, for that tried to configure minimum frequencies for my CPU using **cpufreq-set**

I need to get the correct frequency to limit all cpu's to  minimum 2.00 GHz when using On-Demand governor

Here is some info gathered :

```
cpufreq-info -g
conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance
```

And all CPU's return the same information from coufreq-info

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.67 GHz:19.00%, 2.67 GHz:0.00%, 2.53 GHz:1.78%, 2.40 GHz:0.74%, 2.27 GHz:1.23%, 2.13 GHz:1.24%, 2.00 GHz:1.26%, 1.87 GHz:1.68%, 1.73 GHz:2.11%, 1.60 GHz:2.06%, 1.47 GHz:3.66%, 1.33 GHz:9.65%, 1.20 GHz:55.58%  (2217)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 2.67 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.67 GHz, 2.67 GHz, 2.53 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.27 GHz, 2.13 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.87 GHz, 1.73 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.47 GHz, 1.33 GHz, 1.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.67 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.67 GHz:10.48%, 2.67 GHz:0.00%, 2.53 GHz:0.80%, 2.40 GHz:0.72%, 2.27 GHz:0.69%, 2.13 GHz:0.80%, 2.00 GHz:1.20%, 1.87 GHz:1.10%, 1.73 GHz:1.50%, 1.60 GHz:2.08%, 1.47 GHz:4.91%, 1.33 GHz:9.12%, 1.20 GHz:66.61%  (1858)
```

Comment: An answer depends on which CPU frequency scaling driver you are using. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and maybe on the governor `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: I got acpi-cpufreq and governor performance, but I should change it to conseervative

Comment: The available CPU frequency list is there in your edit. Use 2.00 GHz.

Comment: @DougSmythies OK so no, I can't when I tried to use 2000000 it turned to 2.13 GHz

Comment: I seem to vaguely recall some recent e-mails about some rounding issues. Try a slightly lower number. And / or try using primitives instead of cpufreq-set (Note: I never use anything but primatives) For each CPU (0 shown): `echo 2000000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_min_freq`.

Comment: @DougSmythies And for the governors ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52206/discussion-between-userdepth-and-doug-smythies).

Comment: Your question has become confusing since you removed, what I consider to be important content.

Comment: @DougSmythies I think I might have fixed that u.u

Answer (score 1):

Use the values supplied with **cpufreq-set**

```
cpufreq-set -d 2.00 GHz
```

*Note :*

*This is not working for me but it is what the man page says*